# CreateView Saving prblem?

Tags: django

I have three models.

#Peronal_info Models:

```
class Personal_info(models.Model):
    pinfo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nfullname = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=128)
    efullname = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=128)
    dob_ad = models.DateField()
    dob_bs = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    citizen_no = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    cissue_dist = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cissue_date = models.DateField()
    language = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    p_district = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    p_vdc = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    p_ward = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    telephone = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    mother_name = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=128)
    mother_cit = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    father_name = models.CharField(validators=[max_len_check], max_length=128)
    father_cit = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="photos/", null=True, blank=True)
    cit_image = models.FileField(upload_to="citizens/")
    inclu_image = models.FileField(upload_to="inclusions/", null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.efullname)
```

## Education Models:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    edu_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[max_len_check])
    board = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[max_len_check1])
    pexam = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=16, validators=[max_len_check2])
    tmarks = models.IntegerField()
    percent = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    mainsub = models.CharField(max_length=16, validators=[max_len_check2])
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="educations/", null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.userid)
```

## V_applied Models:

```
class V_applied(models.Model):
    appNo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=add_one)
    p_srlno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=0, default=0)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Vacancy,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inclusive = models.ManyToManyField(Inclusive)
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=128,choices=bank_choice)
    v_no = models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[max_len_check1])
    dep_date = models.DateField()
    ser_fee = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="vouchers/")
    personal_info = models.ForeignKey(Personal_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    education = models.ManyToManyField(Education, blank=True, default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[max_len_check], default="Pending")
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=56, validators=[max_len_check1], default="Pending")
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[max_len_check2], blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager
```

#To save data automatically in ManyToMany Field i.e. in perosnal_info & education fields, there is a function form_valid() in CreateView Class in views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class v_appliedadd(CreateView):
    form_class = V_appliedForm
    template_name = 'v_applied/v_applied_form.html'
    success_url = '/v_applied/vapp_details/'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.userid = self.request.user
        form.instance.personal_info = Personal_info.objects.get(userid=self.request.user)
        instance_from = form.save()
        educationall = Education.objects.filter(userid=self.request.user)
        for edu in educationall:
            instance_edu = Education.objects.get(pk=edu.pk)
            instance_from.education.add(instance_edu)
        instance_from.save()
        instance_from.save_m2m()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Problem is here that while executing this function Error display but while checking table Data is inserted, How to make error free? Error is:

```
AttributeError at /v_applied/v_appliedadd/
'V_applied' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/v_applied/v_appliedadd/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'V_applied' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'
Exception Location: D:\DjangoProject\app_epf\v_applied\views.py in form_valid, line 50
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['D:\\DjangoProject\\app_epf',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 20 Sep 2020 22:42:21 +05
```

It is not being solve, Please help for solution.

Comment: `instance_from = form.save()` is not the form, but the instance wrapped in the form, you should thus use `form.save_m2m()`, not `instance_form.save_m2m()`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried it, even after keeping 'form.save_m2m()' error displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form.save_m2m() rather than instance.save_m2m()
If you need to bypass that error you can use exceptions, but I will not suggest you that:

```
try:
    //smth
except AttributeError :
   // smth
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried it even after keeping 'form.save_m2m()' same error displayed. Any other method to make auto save in m2m field instead my function? Please your  suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The save_m2m() method is only added to a saved ModelForm object **if you passed commit=false** as an argument to the .save method. In your code, you never did this, therefore you are calling .save_m2m needlessly. You get the error because the save_m2m method doesn't exist in your saved ModelForm.

To solve your error, simply remove the call to save_m2m altogether; there is no need for it, and it's throwing an error because the method was never created on the object. (It's worth noting that you also happen to be calling .save_m2m on the wrong object: it should be called on the ModelForm instance, not the new Model class object, as already noted in the comments to your post; but you still get the error after changing it to the form, because the .save_m2m method does not exist in your form).

```
instance_from.save_m2m()    # remove this entire line
```

If you had previously saved your form with commit=False passed as an argument -- perhaps because you needed to do some additional modification to the newly created object before saving it the database -- and your object contained Many2Many connections, then it would be necessary to manually save the new object followed by a call to save_m2m on the ModelForm instance. In your code, however, there is no usage of commit=False, and this step is not necessary, and doing so leads to the error you are receiving.